# Get the Integer behind ImageView Array

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have this [thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofXB.png) into my application.

That I want to do is this, when someone presses the *die with the number 5* I want to add *5 points* into his ArrayList. I was thinking for an **Listener** but how would I know which ImageView has been pressed?

Currently I am using this method to get the *right placeholders* in the board

```
public ImageView[] initiateDice() {
    ImageView pDice1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_one);
    ImageView pDice2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_two);
    ImageView pDice3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_three);
    ImageView pDice4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_four);
    ImageView pDice5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_five);
    ImageView pDice6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_six);
    ImageView pDice7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_seven);
    ImageView pDice8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die_eight);

    ImageView[] placeHolders = new ImageView[] {pDice1, pDice2, pDice3, pDice4, pDice5, pDice6, pDice7, pDice8};
    return placeHolders;
}
```

and I am "printing" the dice on the screen using that method

```
public void printDice(int[] array1, ImageView[] array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array2[i].setImageResource(diceImages[array1[i] - 1]);
        array2[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

where the first array is 8 random generated numbers for the dice and the second array is the PlaceHolders.

The *diceImages* is for the images of the dice, the six states of them.

```
private final int[] diceImages = new int[] {R.drawable.dice_one, R.drawable.dice_two, R.drawable.dice_three, 
        R.drawable.dice_four, R.drawable.dice_five, R.drawable.dice_pico };
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers are providing some of the solution, but you're actually asking about how to get the number displayed in the image view, in which case, you can save it to the tag:

```
public void printDice(int[] array1, ImageView[] array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array2[i].setImageResource(diceImages[array1[i] - 1]);
        array2[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        array2[i].setTag(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

And modifying Matt's answer:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer dieValue = v.getTag();
        // do something
    }
};

pDice1.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice2.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice3.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice4.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice5.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice6.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice6.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice8.setOnClickListnener(listener);
```

Comment: Well thanks very much. I didn't even think for a second the `.setTag()` method and thanks for that. Yeah the other answers were good too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to set an OnClickListener like this:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == pDice1) {
            // do something
        } else if (v == pDice2) {
        ...
        }
    }
};

pDice1.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice2.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice3.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice4.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice5.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice6.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice6.setOnClickListnener(listener);
pDice8.setOnClickListnener(listener);
```

Comment: If all `pDice` variables are local to the `initiateDice()`, he cannot use them inside the anonymous class without declaring them `final`.

Answer (score 0):

You would set an `OnClickListener()` to all `ImageViews`. The `OnClickListener()` gets passed the `View` that has clicked. `View` has a `getId()` that returns an `int` with the id of the `View`. Then it is only a matter of adding either a `switch` or `if(){...} else if(...)()` to perform a specific action based on the id of the `View` that was clicked.